# Java - LWJGL - transperent Texture

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have been looking at many sites and LWJGL tutorials and I'm surprised to find
that there is not very many things explaining how to create a program that uses
transparent textures.

I have used gimp to remove the white in the background of the PNG
image and it turns to the transparent checkerboard, witch seems good and when I open it in windows photo viewer it is fine.

However when opening it into my program it still has the white square around the image, so when two non-transparent images collide it looks awful.

I think by 2012 any game with non-transparent textures looks very unprofessional.

I need to fix this so would someone please point me in the right direction or explain how to sole the problem.

Remember: I'm using LWJGL and the opengl Texture and the opengl TextureLoader with a PNG image edited in gimp to have a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using default pipeline check how to use glBlendFunction.

So basically you will tell openGL how to blend multiple images with alpha values.

Also if you're using glTexImage2D call, make sure source pixel format is GL_RGBA.

Comment: would i call glBlend() before the image is being drawn in the game loop or should this be outside of the gameloop?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code in your initialize code after you enable OpenGL:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

It should now just work.

If you need explanation: You're just telling OpenGL to blend the image's alpha channel with any image below it.